# How to convert multiple SQL left joins to Linq-To-SQL

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a user table, a user_items table, a user_to_group table and a group table.

How would I convert the following SQL query to the correct Linq-to-sql query?

```
select user.username, user.email, user_items.item_number, item_types.desc, [group].name from user
left join user_items on user.user_id = user_items.user_id
left join item_types on user_items.item_type_id = item_types.item_type_id
left join user_to_group on user.user_id = user_to_group.user_id
left join [group] on user_to_group.group_id = [group].group_id
```

I have tried using group joins and joining with DefaultIfEmpty, but I'm unable to return the exact same results as my SQL query.

Thank you.

@ChrisF,

Sure, I could break it down into:

```
select user.username, user.email, user_items.item_number from user 
left join user_items on user.user_id = user_items.user_id
```

Which I have in linq2sql as:

```
var users = (from u in db.users 
join ui in db.user_items on u.user_id equals ui.user_id into useritems from ui in useritems.DefaultIfEmpty() 
select new { user = u, item_number = useritems == null ? string.Empty : useritems.FirstOrDefault().item_number});
```

However, it still doesn't return all the results it should, and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried breaking your SQL down into several steps and converting to LINQ on step at a time? You still might get stuck ;) but you'd have more details to add to the question and a specific point to ask about.

Comment: Sure, I could break it down into:

select user.username, user.email, user_items.item_number from user
left join user_items on user.user_id = user_items.user_id

Which I have in linq2sql as:

var users = (from u in db.users
            join ui in db.user_items on u.user_id equals ui.user_id into useritems
            from ui in useritems.DefaultIfEmpty()                
            select new { user = u, item_number = useritems == null ? string.Empty : useritems.FirstOrDefault().item_number});

however, it still doesn't return all the results it should, and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you edit your question with this information it will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem, I was selecting

```
useritems.FirstOrDefault().item_number
```

Which is what I selected into (and FirstOrDefault!), instead of what I used for my join:

```
ui.item_number
```

So my complete linq query is

```
var users = (from u in db.users
            join ug in db.user_to_groups on p.user_id equals pg.user_id into pgrp
            from ug in pgrp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join g in db.groups on pg.group_id equals g.group_id into groups
            from g in groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join ui in db.user_items on u.user_id equals ui.user_id into useritems 
            from ui in useritems.DefaultIfEmpty()                          

        select new { user = u, item_number = ui == null ? string.Empty : ui.item_number, usergroup = g == null ? string.Empty : g.name});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look at the `join ... into ...` construct.

[Here is an example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

*... Something else to consider ...*
LINQ will allow you to turn your simple table structure into a complex hierarchy.  Another option beyond the left joins would be nested queries.  Maybe something like this...

```
var selected = from user in users
               select new
               {
                   user,
                   items = from item in user_items
                           where item.user_id == user.user_id
                           join it in item_types
                               on item.item_type_id equals it.item_type_id
                           select it,
                   groups = from ug in user_to_groups
                            where ug.user_id == user.user_id
                            join @group in groups
                                on ug.group_id equals @group.group_id
                            select @group.name,
               };
```

Comment: Thanks, I only saw your answer after posting mine. I was using join into, only I was selecting the wrong thing! :)

Answer (score 0):

You query could be written more tersely if you define some associations between your objects:

```
from u in db.Users
from ug in u.User_To_Groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
let g = ug.Group
from ui in u.UserItems.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
  user = u,
  item_number = ui == null ? string.Empty : ui.item_number,
  usergroup = g == null ? string.Empty : g.name
});
```